# List model inherited from QAbstractListModel, list item properties won't update from QML

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qt5

I'm having a difficult time explaining my problem, so I'm just going to make it as simple and hope it does the job. I'm using Qt5 with QtQuick 2.0.

I've created a MyListModel class that inherits from QAbstractListModel, and holds items of type MyListItem. I use it in a QML ListView as a `model: myListModel`, and the delegate displays a `quantity` property from MyListItem, in a lovely TextInput box. Everything works fine.

However, when I change the `quantity` value from the delegate, the items in the model aren't updated. I *know* they're not updated, because my `setQuantity(long desired_quantity)` function, a member of MyListItem, does not run. Long story short, I can't figure out how to actually call the setQuantity function from within the delegate. I can do it manually by adding `Q_PROPERTY(long quantity READ quantity WRITE setQuantity)` to MyListItem, and then using `setContextProperty()` to expose a `MyListItem myTemp` object to QML, and then calling `myTemp.quantity = 10`. But clearly, if the delegate can't write to the quantity property (it can only read from it), it's not doing the job.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I feel like I've tried everything the Qt designers could have possibly expected, and I get nothing. And I can't find any documentation that clearly addresses my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextInput box will not update your c++ model automatically, you have to do this by yourself. You can do this by adding a slot or Q_INVOKABLE method to you model:

```
//add a slot to you model
public slots:
 setDataInModel(const int index, const QVariant &value);
//or add Q_INVOKABLE method:
public:
 Q_INVOKABLE setData(const int index, const QVariant &value);
```

You have to implement one of these methods so that it changes the appropriate data row in your model. Do not forget to call the **dataChanged** method inside of the method after update. You then have to call these methods from QML delegate manually when the TextInput is updated:

```
onAccepted: {
  model.setDataInModel(index, text)
}
```

Here **index** is a property that is defined in each delegate and text is the text from your TextInput.

Comment: That worked. Do you have any comments on why the delegate doesn't simply have a pre-made reference to the list object, instead of just the index? Because in order to have a QSortFilterProxyModel object operate on the model I'm using, I have to subclass the QSortFilterProxyModel and pass a `modifyQuantity()` function back to the original model, right?

Comment: Delegates only read the data from the model when they get signals such as **dataChanged**. So they do not usually need a reference to a list objects. One solution for you would be to add an additional role to you model that returns the unique number of each item. You can then use that when calling model change function instead of the index. You would not have to subclass the QSortFilterProxyModel then.

Comment: The only problem with that idea would be the time it'd take to search for the unique id in the model, correct? In my case, that would probably work well, but I'd be embarrassed to take the shortcut. EDIT: I took the shortcut. It worked beautifully. Damn you for encouraging laziness! (Seriously, thanks for the insights!)